# Angular cli. Cannot find namespace jasmine

Tags: angular, angular-cli

On new project install I'm trying to use jasmine, I'm getting

```
Cannot find namespace Jasmine
```

when trying to reference jasmine.spy

I can see typings folder installed for jasmine under @types with the correct files. Something doesn't seem configured correctly upon project creation.

How is this conifigured in setup so I can go about fixing this?

UPDATE 
upon more diligent reading of the test output, it's spyOn that isn't recognised.

Mac OSX ( El Capitan)
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.17
node: 6.2.0

Comment: Chuck norris doesn't need typings. He can use TypeScript with JS files

Comment: I wish he didn't, they are a pain!

Comment: Is this just an IDE problem? Did you try to run the tests? Maybe some IDEs are behind on the `@types` support. I read a post recently where WebStorm was the problem, and the poster had to just update to the latest WebStorm

Comment: Maybe this is a red herring. I have a different error message in the test output, it's saying it doesn't recognise spyOn, which should be global like jasmine?

Comment: I don't know I never have this problem with CLI. You can try to go with the old school typings `typings install --global dt~jasmine`

Comment: That did it, not sure why that didn't work before, but does now, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you just need to update your global TypeScript. Not sure but I think `@types` was added in TypeScript 2.0